# Removing blank lines from array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have the following code

```
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

ForEach($domain in ((Get-ADForest).Domains)){

ForEach($group in (Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Members -Server $domain | ? {-not $_.members})){

    $temp = [PSCustomObject] @{'1 Security' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Security" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*1*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                               '1 Distro' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Distribution" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*1*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                               '2 Security' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Security" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*2*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                               '2 Distro' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Distribution" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*2*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                               '3 Security' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Security" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*3*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                               '3 Distro' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Distribution" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*3*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name         
                               }

    $array.Add($temp) | Out-Null

}

}


$array
```

This works with a couple of caveats, first there are empty lines in the array elements, how can I remove those?  Second at the end of the array element I want to add another line that would count the total number of items in the element.  The code behind the count I have but adding to the last line of the array is the problem.

Comment: Add `$array.Count` as the last statement in the script?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. Unless you specifically need an ArrayList you might want to just stick with standard array collections. They're easier to make, and more people are familiar with them so any issues you use will be easier to support. As for removing blanks, you could just use a `Where` statement.

```
$array = $array | Where{$_.'1 Security' -or $_.'1 Distro' -or $_.'2 Security' -or $_.'2 Distro' -or $_.'3 Security' -or $_.'3 Distro'}
```

Then you just add one last object at the end that includes the counts for each property.

```
$Counts = [PSCustomObject]@{
                            '1 Security' = $array.'1 Security'.count
                            '1 Distro' = $array.'1 Distro'.count
                            '2 Security' = $array.'2 Security'.count
                            '2 Distro' = $array.'2 Distro'.count
                            '3 Security' = $array.'3 Security'.count
                            '3 Distro' = $array.'3 Distro'.count
                            }
$array += $Counts
```

So changing to use a standard array instead of the arraylist, and adding in those changes the whole thing looks like this:

```
ForEach($domain in ((Get-ADForest).Domains)){

    ForEach($group in (Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Members -Server $domain | ? {-not $_.members})){

        [array]$array += [PSCustomObject] @{'1 Security' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Security" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*1*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                                   '1 Distro' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Distribution" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*1*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                                   '2 Security' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Security" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*2*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                                   '2 Distro' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Distribution" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*2*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                                   '3 Security' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Security" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*3*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
                                   '3 Distro' = $group | ? {$_.GroupCategory -like "Distribution" -and $_.DistinguishedName -like "*3*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name         
                                   }

    }

}

$array = $array | Where{$_.'1 Security' -or $_.'1 Distro' -or $_.'2 Security' -or $_.'2 Distro' -or $_.'3 Security' -or $_.'3 Distro'} 

$Counts = [PSCustomObject]@{
                            '1 Security' = $array.'1 Security'.count
                            '1 Distro' = $array.'1 Distro'.count
                            '2 Security' = $array.'2 Security'.count
                            '2 Distro' = $array.'2 Distro'.count
                            '3 Security' = $array.'3 Security'.count
                            '3 Distro' = $array.'3 Distro'.count
                            }
$array += $Counts
$array
```